# OAuth in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I am trying to implement Oauth in google app engine on python. For my application i am using gae sessions and my model to authenticate users. It will be more helpful for me. .If you could provide some examples..

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html

Comment: Are you trying to be an OAuth provider, or consumer?

Comment: I want to both provide Oauth provider and consumer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check out the following resources:

The [App Engine OAuth Library](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library), which has support for Dropbox, Twitter, MySpace, and LinkedIn.

The [Tipfy](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/) Framework (EDIT: links removed to the now defunct tipfy.org).

Using those as a basis, even if you can't use the libraries themselves, you'll have some solid, working examples of how to use OAuth on App Engine.

Answer (score 4):

here's an alternative that supports oauth 1.0, 2.0 and openid:

https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth