# how to import a python package to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Sorry if it is a stupid question.
Normally when I need a package, I import filename.py.
How is about this https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2 ? How can I import this package since I cannot find oauth2.py file.

Do I copy this oauth2 folder to project root and then do import oauth2?

I am just a beginner so can you give me detail instruction?
Thanks for your time

Comment: how is that you don't get any error doing `import filename.py`?

Answer (score 2):

Read [**this**](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages) first.

Now if you check out [`oauth2/__init__.py`](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py), you will see oauth already do `import httplib2` so you don't have to import it yourself. (Unless you also are using httplib2, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you are correct. If you want to use a python package in a GAE app you have to have a copy of it it in the applications root directory where it can be accessed by your application as a normal import. It will then be uploaded along with your applications code and be usable when deployed too.

There are exceptions where you don't have to do this as the library is provided for you, you can read about those here: [Supported 3rd Party Libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

For those you need to edit your app.yaml.

For oauth2 you should look at google specific implementations. I don't know what you've linked to there, all I know is the endless stream of oauth/gae questions usually end up here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview

Comment: thanks for helping. I am doing import httplib2 and
import oauth2 as oauth in views.py. However, it seems like oauth2 depends on httplib2, so do I have to go inside oauth2 to add 'import httplib2'? if so, where should I add that in oauth2, I am so confused.

Comment: I can't remember TBH. Similar question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246029/oauth-in-google-app-engine